# Attach 1 or more (non image) files to rails application, with having to install an image-processing library

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, attachment, attachment-fu

I'm currently learning rails by creating a simple project management app. I've gotten to the point where I would like to be allow a user upload multiple files - pdfs, docs, xls etc. The user only needs to be able to attach one file at a time, but the possibilty to have multiple documents associated with a project is a must.

I've spent quite a lot of time researching my options, and it appears the two main plugins are attachment_fu and paperclip. From what I've read though, these appear to concentrate specifically on the upload and subsequent resizing of images, something I couldn't care less about. Is there a simpler way to achieve what I'm trying?

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might still consider using attachment_fu or paperclip as those are the "standard" libraries for such tasks. And they work fine for any kind of file.

Comment: +1 for paperclip. I'm fairly certain you don't need an image library unless you're using features which require it (ie resizing)

Answer (score 0):

The multi-upload can't be made without JS or Flash now. You need add some hack in your view to manage it.